# PHP - Serverside console output

Tags: php

i'm using PHP as a server backend, to create API, and hence it doesn't console log to browser.

However I'm finding it very hard to debug without using console, and I have to use `error_log(json_encode($variable))` all the time to write to error log to see what is being returned/received.

Is there anyway I can 'monitor' the API, and use console.log or similar to write to somewhere, where I can view my output live?

Thanks @Chris, for answering my need. So I'm using the following codes to do a simple print to text file and use tail to see the live output. Works brilliantly.

```
function mylog($data) {
$myFile = "/home/user/html/log.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: Use XDebug for proper debugging.

Comment: you can use xdebug or log error in file or
you can use https://stackify.com/13-ways-to-tail-a-log-file-on-windows-unix/ to view errors in error_log live

Comment: xdebug does it only work on web application? i’m using react native to call php so php is entirely backend.

Comment: How do You run the PHP backend?

Comment: Sorry i may not know the right terms to use. My react native application just call the API for e.g. example.com/get/listing/ then it will return something. However during debugging for the API sometimes i want to know the $_GET or $_POST values received.. so I use error_log now

Comment: When i use PHP for web application to generate the HTML, i know i can just printe it to the browser console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice would be to write to a log file within your PHP:

```
$myFile = "log.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, "write this to my file\n");
fclose($fh);
```

If you have command line access then you can run this command to view the contents of the file live:

```
tail -f log.txt
```

This will then show anything written to the file immediately.

Comment: can you advise how do I add a "pretty" var_dump if i were to write to text file? Because there's many Json returns

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial You could use `print_r($something, true);`, this will pretty-print the variable and return it as a string.

Comment: thank u, i added fwrite($fh, json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)); to the code and now it's working beautifully. Not perfect for debugging but enough for me. thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

This might help.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

as this will show errors when you call an API. You can check the errors by clicking on the API call made.

Comment: This will only show error and warning notifications, but in his question was mentioned a **variable dump**.